# java framework for a web wizard

Tags: java, wizard

I'd like to create a web wizard or a wizard on/within a website.

I know there are several java frameworks for wizards but there is none for the web in particular.

If I search for a framework, I always get wizards to create a website, applet, servlet and what not. But never how to create such a wizard itself.

So the question(s) is:
What framework should I use to create a web wizard?
And what frameworks are there?

The wizard will be the visualisation for a BPEL Process deployment on a apache ode.

I thought a webapp would be an easy way because the apache is running anyway.
I'm not bound to that, perhaps someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A webapp seems to be a good approach in your case.

Unfortunately, there isn't any framework that manages wizards only. All of the existing web frameworks, like Wicket, Tapestry, Ruby-on-Rails, Django and so on, deal with a much larger set of functionalities. A wizard is rarely included as a distinct, ready-to-use feature because it is quite easy to develop one with the tools supplied by the framework. As a consequence, you will have to adopt a general-purpose web framework and use it to develop a wizard.

Most likely, if you have to develop just a wizard, you should use something lighter and simpler than Wicket, Tapestry, Rails or Diango. Probably you should use someting like Padrino (Ruby-based, but there are "clones" of Padrino in many languages).

Googling around, you *can* find a framework that includes a ready-to-use wizard or a wizard plug-in. A wizard is a common need and it is more than possible that someone else has already developed something like that. Unfortunately, you will have to focus your attention on a few specific frameworks and investigate in depth about their features/plug-ins (because of the Google misunderstanding you experimented already).

PS: If Java is not mandatory, I would avoid it. It is probably easier and faster to develop such an application with Sinatra/Padrino (Ruby-based) or Bottle/Flask (Python-based). Django (Python-based) could be a good alternative, as well.